# How to make a Numpy vectorized function that looks at current index and previous index?

Tags: python, numpy

I am wanting to create a function that is vectorized (really just for sake of knowledge) instead of iterating through a numpy array with a for loop. My intention is to get the ith value and the i+1th value and calculate the velocity.

My pseudo function would be as follows:

```
def get_velocity(position_array, timestamp_array):
   magnitude = np.linalg.norm(position_array [i + 1] - position_array [i])
   return magnitude / (timestamp_array[i + 1 ] - timestamp_array[i])
```

I am not sure how to tie in the indexing though when calling a vectorized function.

Comment: Look at `x[1:]-x[:-1]` to take multiple differences.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am most likely trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. Your method essentially gets the difference from each neighboring index and doesn't require to try to vectorize or iterate through the array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "vectorized".  To me, proper `numpy` vectorization means using methods such as I suggested to operate on whole arrays (in compiled code).  It means avoiding Python level iteration where possible.